# Generate independent pseudo-random number sequences - fortran 90

Tags: random, fortran

I am relatively new to Fortran 90 and despite having scoured a lot of manuals, forums, tutorials, university pages, and books, I have not managed to modify the F90 routine below using the system clock so that the random numbers generated (in [0,1]) are independent from one run to another.

```
! Simple random number generator in the range [0,1]
! ranset_(iseed) initializes with iseed
! ranf_() returns next random number

      real function ranf_()
       implicit none
       real rand_
!       ranf_ = rand_(0)
        call random_number(ranf_)
       return
      end

      subroutine ranset_(iseed)
      implicit none
      real rand_,ranf_
      integer iseed, i, m, nsteps
!      i = rand_(1) ! reinitialize (reset)
      nsteps = iseed*10000
      do i = 1,nsteps
        m = ranf_()
!       m = rand_(0)
      end do
      return
      end  

      real function rand_(iseed)
      implicit none
      integer iseed
      integer ia1, ia0, ia1ma0, ic, ix1, ix0, iy0, iy1
      save ia1, ia0, ia1ma0, ic, ix1, ix0
      data ix1, ix0, ia1, ia0, ia1ma0, ic/0,0,1536,1029,507,1731/
      if (iseed.ne.0) then
        ia1 = 1536
        ia0 = 1029
        ia1ma0 = 507
        ic = 1731
        ix1 = 0
        ix0 = 0
        rand_ = 0
      else
       iy0 = ia0*ix0
       iy1 = ia1*ix1 + ia1ma0*(ix0-ix1) + iy0
       iy0 = iy0 + ic
       ix0 = mod (iy0, 2048)
       iy1 = iy1 + (iy0-ix0)/2048
       ix1 = mod (iy1, 2048)
       rand_ = ix1*2048 + ix0
       rand_ = rand_ / 4194304.
      end if
      return
      end
```

The code is not that easy to fully understand for a beginner like me.
Any insights/suggestions/solutions on how to properly do this using the system clock?

Comment: I would not go as far as to ask how to generate "truly" random numbers algorithmic-ally, it is not possible. It would be a pseudo-random number.

Comment: I believe it is possible by adding some noise to the pseudo-random number generator, this noise being based on the system clock for instance.

Comment: Certainly not off of the system clock. The source would have to be a truly random event in nature, such as atmospheric noise or radioactive decay.

Comment: A lot of people in my field have used this method so that the pseudo-random numbers generated are not the same from one rune to another, the system clock being able to provide different numbers for every run. If you can provide any help on this issue don't hesitate.

Comment: Context is important here. If you need a random number generator to drive your high-stakes poker game, then pseudo-random numbers will not be sufficient (unless you are confident that you can protect your seed values, which should never be the system clock). If you need a random number for some trivial task such as automated testing, it will be good enough.

Comment: I need to run an atmosphere model several times using different pseudo-random number sequences in order to test the sensitivity of this model to noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of such initialization, which you can just copy and use directly, is in the gfortran manual. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html

With many compilers you can just run `RANDOM_SEED()` without arguments and they set the sequence in the processor-dependent manner using the clock. Gfortran however does not use the clock in this case. Therefore use the subroutine from the link to the manual.

Comment: Agreed, the clock is not random, but it can be used to initialize different pseudo-random sequences - which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Then read the link...

Comment: I have been through this manual page, unsuccessfully. I was also looking for help as to how to modify the code snippet.

Comment: What have you tried with it then? What did it cause? You can just copy and paste the code from there and call `random_number()`.

Comment: @user222552, It seems that you expect S.O users to rewrite your code to do what you want. Although S.O is here to help, it is not there to learn the language for you. You need to be able to copy a well-written subroutine and use it. I do not know how complete an example would have been.

Comment: @VladimirF calling `RANDOM_SEED()` before `RANDOM_NUMBER() ` solved the problem: the pseudo-random number sequences produced by several runs are different.